# Flow wait for first, then process the rest in background

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a flow of something. And I have to write function that returns the first item as soon as possible, and all following calls to that functions returns the latest value of the flow.

```
val f = flow {
    emit(1)
    delay(100)
    emit(2)
}

suspend fun getLatest() = f.conflate().first() // this should be fixed, something like latest()

suspend fun main() {
    println(getLatest())
    delay(100)
    println(getLatest())
    delay(100)
    println(getLatest())
    delay(100)
    println(getLatest())
}
```

The output should be ones at first, and after some times, always twos. The code above return s always ones and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Flow` are cold streams. Every time you call `first()`, block

```kotlin
    emit(1)
    delay(100)
    emit(2)
```

will be called again.

In future, `SharedFlow` will be added into library, see [pull request](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/pull/2069), we can write like this:

```kotlin
val f = flow {
    emit(1)
    delay(100)
    emit(2)
}

val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope = ...
val shared = f.conflate().shareIn(
        coroutineScope,
        replay = 1,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed()
)

suspend fun getLatest() = shared.first() // this should be fixed, something like latest()

suspend fun main() {
    println(getLatest())
    delay(100)
    println(getLatest())
    delay(100)
    println(getLatest())
    delay(100)
    println(getLatest())
}
```